# WPF MVVM ContextMenu Bound to ObservableCollection<string> Command Not Firing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, bind

I am trying to bind an  ObservableCollection to a ContextMenu using MVVM. But when i try to fire the command nothing is happening. also, i need to pass the string as command parameter to the event.

**Below is the xaml code:**

```
<ContextMenu Name="ctxAddApplication" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ApplicationTypes}">
  <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
      <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding AddRequirementCommand}"/>
      <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
    </Style>
  </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

**Below is the View Model Code:**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ApplicationTypes { get; private set; }

public ComposableCommand AddRequirementCommand { get; private set; }

this.AddRequirementCommand = new ComposableCommand(this.AddRequirementView);

private void AddRequirementView(object applicationName) {}
```

Please help !!!

Comment: Please format the xaml. It is hard to read this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case you need the code:

```
<ContextMenu Name="ctxAddApplication" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ApplicationTypes}">
                <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext.AddRequirementCommand}"/>
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ContextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

The data context for each menu item will be whatever it is bound to. In your case, a string because your `ApplicationTypes` property is a collection of strings. Thus, your binding to set the command won't work because there is no `AddRequirementCommand` property on type `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside ContextMenu view for each item is bound to the item from the collection.

```
<Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding AddRequirementCommand}" />
```

this will try to locate 'AddRequirementCommand' in string class. Use RelativeSource in this Binding. Also use VS debugger and Output window to see binding errors, it helps a lot usually.